# how to connect an Angular7+ application to an outside nodejs api?

Tags: node.js, angular

app.js file

```
var express=require("express");
var cors=require("cors");

var mongoclient=require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var bodyparser=require("body-parser");

var url="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";
var app=express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.get("/getemp",function(req,res){

    mongoclient.connect(url,function(err,db){
        var dbo=db.db("login");
        dbo.collection("emp").find().toArray(function(err,doc){
            if(!err){
                res.send(doc);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

i am trying to connect  this nodejs api file  to angular application.i am using this much of code but at this time i am facing error "server not listening the specific port number".as i am beginner to this technology.

Comment: You need to add a listener for the server. `app.listen(4242)`. Use any port number you like. Then you can request using `http://localhost:4242`

Comment: please check here : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: you have  listen to a port `app.listen('8080', () => console.log("Example app listening on port 8080"))`